# ARM `CSET` condition encoding (as vs docu)

Tags: assembly, encoding, arm, opcode

TL;DR `cset` code generated by assembler uses different *condition codes* than ARM manual.

---

I do not understand how the conditions are encoded for the `cset` instruction.

I have troubles understanding why the assembler generates different binary code than what I would expect after looking at the [*ARM Architecture Reference Manual - ARMv8*](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/db/DDI0487D_b_armv8_arm.pdf).

The GNU assembler on my pi3 generates following code for different `cset` checks (I confirmed that the code works as expected):

```
9a 9f 17 e0        cset    x0, eq  // eq = none
9a 9f 07 e0        cset    x0, ne  // ne = any
9a 9f b7 e0        cset    x0, ge  // ge = tcont
9a 9f a7 e0        cset    x0, lt  // lt = tstop
9a 9f d7 e0        cset    x0, gt
9a 9f c7 e0        cset    x0, le
```

The interesting part here are bit 12-15 (the 5th nibble from the left) it encodes the condition (*cond*), as shown in the manual:

[image: CSET documentation from the ARM Architecture manual]

Using the `cset` documentation and the assembler output one can extract following table:

```
+------+----------+
| cond | mnemonic |
|------+----------|
| 0001 | EQ       |
| 0000 | NE       |
| 1011 | GE       |
| 1010 | LT       |
| 1101 | GT       |
| 1100 | LE       |
+------+----------+
```

The confusion now starts when one looks at the *condition codes* in the ARM manual:

[image: Condition encoding as stated in the ARM Architecture manual]

They are the **opposite**!

```
+-----------------+----------+
|    ASSEMBLER    |  MANUAL  |
+------+----------+----------+
| cond | mnemonic | mnemonic |
|------+----------+----------|
| 0001 | EQ       | NE       |
| 0000 | NE       | EQ       |
| 1011 | GE       | LT       |
| 1010 | LT       | GE       |
| 1101 | GT       | LE       |
| 1100 | LE       | GT       |
+------+----------+----------+
```

Could someone please point out to me the 'obvious' error I am making?

Comment: The manual says: _"This instruction is an alias of CSINC. The equivalent instruction is CSINC Wd, WZR, WZR, invert(cond)."_ Hence the negated codes.

Comment: Okay. Is it reasonable to argue that the manual should state that more prominent?

Comment: It's quite prominent to me. It's even mentioned twice. Once in the part I quoted where it says "invert" and also in the legend for the layout you showed as: _"<cond> Is one of the standard conditions, excluding AL and NV, encoded in the "cond" field with its least significant bit inverted."_